# Is it possible to use cocos2d transitions on a CCNode?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Every example I see on how to use transitions is with CCScene like this:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionCrossFade transitionWithDuration:0.5f scene:[NewScene scene]]];
```

My app is setup with a GameScene, MenuScene ..etc. Within the GameScene I setup the DPad and the HUD and under that I have the hero moving to different levels which are of type CCNode.  I want to use the native transitions to move from one level to the next.

I found a question similar [to what I need here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8406438/how-transition-between-layers-in-cocos2d) but that user was essentially told to build the transitions himself.

The confusing part to me is that CCNode contains a method called:

```
- (void) onEnterTransitionDidFinish
```

So, is there a way to use transitions with CCNode that I'm missing?  Is my app setup incorrectly and the levels should be CCScene?  If so how to I keep the HUD and Dpad over the transition?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

`CCTransitions` are specifically for scenes. `CCNodes` contain `onEnterTransitionDidFinish`, as it gets called on every `CCNode` child of a `CCScene`. Fortunately, you can just check the CCTransition code and see how they are implemented and then roll your own for layers (many have done and shared this).

For example, I wrote a simple little method which will use blocks to give the same fade-in, fade-out effect as a scene transition, but for an individual layer (along with some added features). Just pass in the layer you want to cover up, the speed of the fade out and fade in, the color to fade to, and the block you wish to execute while the layer is hidden.

```
-(void)fadeLayer:(CCLayer*)layer withOutDuration:(float)outTime inDuration:(float)inTime color:(ccColor3B)color withBlock: (void(^)())block
{
    CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
    CCLayerColor *toplayer = [CCLayerColor layerWithColor:ccc4(color.r, color.g, color.b, 0) width:winSize.width height:winSize.height];

    [layer addChild:toplayer z:INT_MAX];

    [toplayer runAction:
      [CCSequence actions:
       [CCFadeIn actionWithDuration:outTime],
       [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:block],
       [CCFadeOut actionWithDuration:inTime],
       [CCCallBlockN actionWithBlock:^(CCNode *node) {
          [node removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
       }],
      nil]
    ];
}
```